# Issue with snapshot using delta on spark-dbt

Tags: snapshot, dbt

I'm creating dbt snapshot on spark using Delta Lake. But after the Initial `dbt snapshot` run, from the second `dbt snapshot` command onwards, i'm getting the error snapshot:

> target is not a snapshot table (missing "dbt_scd_id", "dbt_valid_from", "dbt_valid_to")

I'm using local spark, using thriftserver by executing `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh` command. I'm storing the tables and datasets on `s3`

Comment: what version of `dbt-spark` are you running?

Comment: also can you manually verify by querying that your snapshot table exists and has those columns?

Comment: Hey Ashish, I've got a few follow-up questions and debugging steps for you over in https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-spark/issues/199!

Comment: @AndersSwanson dbt version is `0.20.0` and yes, I queried hive metastore using beeline and the table with extra metadata fields are present